# Drive transfers using Google Data Transfer API in C#

Tags: c#, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am writing this code to transfer all drive data from one user to another using the Drive Transfer API with a service account with Domain Wide delegation enabled.

```
    string oldowner = "oldowner@xyz.com";
    string newowner = "newowner@xyz.com";

        DirectoryService dir_service = Build_Directory_Service();
        var olduser = dir_service.Users.Get(oldowner).Execute();
        var newuser = dir_service.Users.Get(newowner).Execute();

        DataTransferService dtservice = Build_DataTransfer_Service();
        DataTransfer dataXfer = new DataTransfer();
        dataXfer.OldOwnerUserId = olduser.Id;
        dataXfer.NewOwnerUserId = newuser.Id;

        dataXfer.ApplicationDataTransfers[0].ApplicationId = 55656082996;
        dataXfer.ApplicationDataTransfers[0].ApplicationTransferParams[0].Key= "PRIVACY_LEVEL";
        dataXfer.ApplicationDataTransfers[0].ApplicationTransferParams[0].Value.Add("PRIVATE");
        dataXfer.ApplicationDataTransfers[0].ApplicationTransferParams[0].Value.Add("SHARED");

        Console.WriteLine("Starting Data transfer from " + oldowner + " to " + newowner);
        dtservice.Transfers.Insert(dataXfer).Execute();
```

But I get this error :

**"Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."**

The stacktrace points to this line where the exception is thrown:

```
    dataXfer.ApplicationDataTransfers[0].ApplicationId = 55656082996;
```

I am following this documentation for the API: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/data-transfer/v1/reference/transfers#resource

But probably I am not setting the values for the transfer resource in a right manner. I need help in assigning the values correctly to the transfer resource.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you post its StackTrace?

Comment: Thanks for checking. I edited the post to include the line at which the exception is thrown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so based on your comments, I would add

```
dataXfer.ApplicationDataTransfers = new List<ApplicationDataTransfer>();
```

Before the line that is throwing. After all, there is a null object and it doesn't look like `ApplicationDataTransfers` is initialized.

Comment: Thanks but didn't work: "the type name 'ApplicationDataTransfers' does not exist in the type 'DataTransfer'"

Comment: what's `typeof(dataXfer.ApplicationDataTransfers)`?

Comment: IList<ApplicationDataTransfer>. If it helps, the API documentation is here: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/data-transfer/v1/reference/transfers#resource

Comment: Worked with a senior colleague of mine who's a C# expert and he also advised the same fix as you did. It works now. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 0):

For everyone's benefit, I am posting my fixed code. Basically the need here is to initialize every List which is needed later in the code. Hope this helps others.

DataTransferService dtservice = Build_DataTransfer_Service();

```
        DataTransfer dataXfer2 = new DataTransfer()
        {
            Kind = "admin#datatransfer#DataTransfer",
            OldOwnerUserId = olduser.Id,
            NewOwnerUserId = newuser.Id,
            ApplicationDataTransfers = new List<ApplicationDataTransfer>()
        };

        ApplicationDataTransfer item = new ApplicationDataTransfer()
        {
            ApplicationId = (long)55656082996,
            ApplicationTransferParams = new List<ApplicationTransferParam>()
        };
        item.ApplicationTransferParams.Add(new ApplicationTransferParam()
        {
            Key = "PRIVACY_LEVEL",
            Value =
                new List<string>() { "PRIVATE",
            "SHARED" }
        });

        dataXfer2.ApplicationDataTransfers.Add(item);

        Console.WriteLine("Starting Data transfer from " + oldowner + " to " + newowner);
        TransfersResource.InsertRequest req = dtservice.Transfers.Insert(dataXfer2);

        var resp2=req.Execute();

        Console.WriteLine("Initial OverTransferStatusCode = " + resp2.OverallTransferStatusCode);
        Console.WriteLine("TransferID = " + dataXfer2.Id);
```